# GAE: Uploading to Blobstore Service kills the Session

Tags: java, html, google-app-engine, jsp, servlets

So I'm using GAE and created a session to persist some data between some JSP and servlets. The problem is when I access the Blobstore Service to upload a file, the session is killed and the user is logged out.

This is the form attributes that causes the problem:
action="<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload") %>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: This should work. If I save something in session in JSP I can retrieve it in upload handler.

Comment: This is the minimum example that works: http://pastebin.com/RDFaqcgc

Comment: Just would like to add that there are some cases where it works. It's not replicable for me. Sometimes the session is still alive, but sometimes it's dead. Weird.

Comment: Check cookies (print them out to console) and compare between working/nonworking sessions.

Comment: Thanks Peter Knego, will try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking at this in the future, it seems this issue only happens when working in the *local development server* but **not** after deploying the app.

I had an identical issue while testing on my local dev server. Uploading files to the GAE Blobstore logged the user out and messed up the session. After I deployed my app, everything worked perfectly online. Wish I had tried that first before spending hours trying to find out how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the session is being killed based on the blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/test") changing the domain in the development environment. If i test using my dev machine IP address the session is destroyed as the call back URL results in computername:port/test rather than ipaddress:port/test. I f i use computername in the URL to submit the form originally the session remains and dev is happy.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Eclipse for development, you can validate each of your jsps prior to deploying.  If you clear all errors first, the compile errors will go away.  I have been surprised at the errors the dev environment did not complain about, but prevented deployment.